# Multivariate (3D) Interpolation Using Vandermonde Matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, interpolation

I can't seem to figure out how to implement the Vandermonde Matrix into Multivariate Interpolation. I am able to get the actual matrix, but I don't understand how to get the values (array) c00,c01,c02... . I know that c = V/z, but I feel like I am missing something (perhaps, not division?). I also know that I need to somehow set up a system of equations (the columns of V are each cij).

> How do you do this in python?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
z = [3.2, 4.4, 6.5, 2.5, 4.7, 5.8, 5.1, 3.6, 2.9]
numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyvander2d(x, y, [2,2])
>>>array([[  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
   [  1.,   2.,   4.,   1.,   2.,   4.,   1.,   2.,   4.],
   [  1.,   3.,   9.,   1.,   3.,   9.,   1.,   3.,   9.],
   [  1.,   1.,   1.,   2.,   2.,   2.,   4.,   4.,   4.],
   [  1.,   2.,   4.,   2.,   4.,   8.,   4.,   8.,  16.],
   [  1.,   3.,   9.,   2.,   6.,  18.,   4.,  12.,  36.],
   [  1.,   1.,   1.,   3.,   3.,   3.,   9.,   9.,   9.],
   [  1.,   2.,   4.,   3.,   6.,  12.,   9.,  18.,  36.],
   [  1.,   3.,   9.,   3.,   9.,  27.,   9.,  27.,  81.]])
```

`np.dot(V, c.flat)`and `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d(x, y, c)` I think have to be incorporated into this somehow, but I don't know what to do. Please help!
I am supposed to output:
`c = V \ z
c =
    0.97500
   -5.27500
    5.95000
   -3.92500
   19.82500
  -21.55000
    3.40000
  -14.70000
   18.50000`

Here is the site where I got this example (They used MatLab):
https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/05Interpolation/multi/
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Given positions x and y:

```
x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

and function values z:

```
z = [3.2, 4.4, 6.5, 2.5, 4.7, 5.8, 5.1, 3.6, 2.9]
```

V will be the Vandermonde matrix:

```
V = numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyvander2d(x, y, [2,2])

V = array([[  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
           [  1.,   2.,   4.,   1.,   2.,   4.,   1.,   2.,   4.],
           [  1.,   3.,   9.,   1.,   3.,   9.,   1.,   3.,   9.],
           [  1.,   1.,   1.,   2.,   2.,   2.,   4.,   4.,   4.],
           [  1.,   2.,   4.,   2.,   4.,   8.,   4.,   8.,  16.],
           [  1.,   3.,   9.,   2.,   6.,  18.,   4.,  12.,  36.],
           [  1.,   1.,   1.,   3.,   3.,   3.,   9.,   9.,   9.],
           [  1.,   2.,   4.,   3.,   6.,  12.,   9.,  18.,  36.],
           [  1.,   3.,   9.,   3.,   9.,  27.,   9.,  27.,  81.]])
```

Each row:

```
a = x[i]
b = y[i]
V[i,:] = [ 1, b, b², a, a*b, a*b², a², a²b, a²b²]
```

A linear interpolation aims to solve:

$$z = V \cdot c$$

therefore we need to solve:

$$c = V^{-1} z$$

```
c = np.linalg.solve(V, z)
```

c now holds the coefficients in the same orders as the Vandermonde matrix does.

You can evaluate it manually:

```
def poly_eval(x, y, z):
    return z[0] + z[1]*y + z[2]*np.power(y,2) + z[3]*x + z[4]*x*y + z[5]*x*np.power(y,2) + z[6]*np.power(x,2) + z[7]*np.power(x,2)*y + z[8]*np.power(x,2)*np.power(y,2)
```

or use

```
np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d([1,2], [3,4], c)
Out[22]: array([-65.5, -88.4])
```